# 404 Not found when calling Web API using Attribute routing

Tags: api, xamarin.forms, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to get a call to an attribute route in my ASP.NET Web API 5.27 to work but Im getting a 404 Not Found error. I have searched extensively for this.
My app is a Xamarin.Forms developed with VS2019.
The call works in the browser of real the testing device but not from the app.

Here is my setup:

```
public class OrdersController : ApiController
{
    private readonly OrdersDbContext db = new OrdersDbContext();

    // GET: api/Orders/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Order))]
    [Route("Order/{Id}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetOrder(int Id)
    {
        var order = await db.Orders.Where(w => w.OrderId == Id).Select(s => s)
            .FirstAsync();                

        if (order == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(order);
    }
}

public class DataService : IDataService
{
    readonly HttpClient _client;

    public DataService()
    {
        _client = new HttpClient()
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(Constants.BaseUrl)
        };
    }
    public async Task<Order> GetNewOrder(NewOrderDetails details)
    {
        var uri = $"Order/1";
        var response = await _client.GetStringAsync(uri);
        var order = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Order>(response);

        return order;
    }
```

}

Comment: Is your url  https?

Comment: No it is not Https

Comment: are you checking in android?

Comment: You should add android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" inside <application> tag in android manifest . May be it will solve the problem

Comment: Yes I have Samsung Galaxy Note 3 to test with

Comment: No that didnt work.

Comment: Check that you configure your HttpConfiguration via the `MapHttpAttributeRoutes` method before any ASP.NET MVC routing registration.

Comment: Do you have an order with an ID of the one being requested? Or are you getting a 404 because the order is not found?

Comment: As I said I can call the action from a web browser and I get the correct order. And yes I do have the MapHttpAttributeRoutes config setup.

Comment: Maybe there are no default values defined for your route.you could refer to [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/debugging-asp-net-web-api-with-route-debugger/),maybe your issue is similar to it

Comment: Try logging the url used to to call the API. Because it seems that the API is working fine, there is a problem in how your app forms the call.

Comment: Try accessing the API from the browser of the phone. Maybe there is a CORS problem https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api.

Comment: From Android 8 onwards HTTP calls are not allowed you need to check that as well. By cleartext traffic flag.